# I need to export .DMP file from oracle 11g please suggest with step related error has mentioned

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export, database-administration

How can I resolve this issue and how to get proper export using Putty (linux).

```
[oracle@oracledb ~]$ exp
Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed Jul 1 14:23:16 2015
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

        Username: CORP_DM
        Password:
            Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 -    
            64bit Production
            With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing 
            options
            Enter array fetch buffer size: 4096 >

            Export file: expdat.dmp > CORP_DM_01072015

            (1)E(ntire database), (2)U(sers), or (3)T(ables): (2)U >

            Export grants (yes/no): yes >

            Export table data (yes/no): yes >

            Compress extents (yes/no): yes >

             Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 
             NCHAR character set

            About to export specified users ...
            User to be exported: (RETURN to quit) >

            Export terminated successfully without warnings.
```

Comment: Forget the older export and use the data pump `EXPDP`.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B thank you very much sir ,can you explain  steps to take backup using expdp please. its need full

Comment: If you are not verse with the expdp feature, then you could do it easily through SQL Developer tool. Here is a doc showing step by step process http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I'm not seeing an error, it appears that your export is being created successfully.  What error are you trying to resolve?

Comment: How about reading the [expdp documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624) ?

Comment: I don't see any error; but you don't seem to be supplying any users when prompted - you're just hitting return which quits as the prompt says. So there will be nothing actually exported. That isn't an error, it's a mistake. But yes, look into expdp anyway.

Comment: Thank You ver much @Justin Cave  ,Note :-  "Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 
  NCHAR character set"  This is exact issue , export created successfully but  without data , here created only blank schema

Comment: The part you're quoting appears to be a statement of fact not an error.  If your actual problem is that the export does not have your data, that's a completely different issue.  Are you saying that the metadata (DDL) is exported successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You are being prompted to supply a user to export:

```
About to export specified users ...
User to be exported: (RETURN to quit) >
```

That means the `CORP_DM` user you are connecting as has the `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` privilege; if it didn't then you would not see that prompt and that user's objects would be exported automatically.

When you are prompted you are not supplying a value, which means you just quit the export (as the prompt says) without doing any work, and end up with an (almost) empty and pointless dump file.

So provide the user when prompted. Assuming you just want to export `CORP_DM` enter that at the fist user prompt, and hit return at the second one to tell export that you are done:

```
About to export specified users ...
User to be exported: (RETURN to quit) > CORP_DM

User to be exported: (RETURN to quit) >

. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user CORP_DM
... etc.
```

As mentioned in comments, consider using [data pump export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm) rather than the [desupported original export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm):

> Original Export is desupported for general use as of Oracle Database 11g. The only supported use of original Export in Oracle Database 11g is backward migration of XMLType data to Oracle Database 10g release 2 (10.2) or earlier. Therefore, Oracle recommends that you use the new Data Pump Export and Import utilities, except in the following situations  which require original Export and Import:
>
> - You want to import files that were created using the original Export utility (exp).
> - You want to export files that will be imported using the original Import utility (imp). An example of this would be if you wanted to export data from Oracle Database 10g and then import it into an earlier database release.